# PWM level shift

Tags: transistors, pwm, switching, level-shifting, negative-voltage

I have a 10 kHz PWM (0V (LOW) to 3V3 (HIGH)) which I wish to level shift as following; when PWM is high (3V3) the output should be 0V while when PWM is low (0V) the output should be -12V. Ideally this has to be done using discreate components (NPN/PNP transistors) while providing some sort of isolation (optical) between the 3V3 and -12V rails.  In terms of current capabilities, the PWM pin can source/sink 8 to 12 mA max while I need not more than 200 mA for the -12V rail. Another requirement worth mentioning are the transient requirements, looking to have a clean 0 to -12V PWM signal.

So far, I came up with this circuit, but it is not behaving as I needed. Any recommendations/tips are much apricated. Thanks[image: CCT][image]

Comment: *but it is not behaving as I needed* - please explain why. Why do you need isolation when both sides of the opto are shown (in your diagram) connected to a common 0 volts/GND?

Comment: @Andyaka sorry  I am new to this, how can I post and other photo of the simulation result?

Comment: @andyaka isolation is not critical for this, but since the PWM is comming from an FPGA, and switching a -12V rail, prevents issues, in hardware they are two differnet gnds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you just need to use a decent high speed isolator with a buffered output like this: -

[image]

Available from virtually everyone including [RS components](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/optocoupler-ics/6935921/). Of course, if you want to do it on the "el cheapo" you'll need a much lower load impedance than 10 kΩ and the addition of a buffer driver to give you 12 volt output compatibility. The RS part costs a couple of quid. I wouldn't waste my time trying to design something that gets anywhere near to the above ACPL-4800 performance.

Comment: Alternatively you could use a digital isolator, SPI/I2C and some DAC placed on the secondary side. This assuming the PWM comes from a MCU and not some other source.

Comment: @andyaka I don't have that avail, I have VOH1016, do you think that this will do the job?

Comment: @Lundin, as i prev. mentioned, isolation is not the most importnat factor, what I mostly need is the correct output, a 0 to -12V pwm signal

Comment: @SJ28 yes, that device also appears suitable and is very similar to the one I posted in my answer. Just try it and see.

Comment: @andyaka, correct me if I'm wrong, I think that both devices can't handel -ve volatges ?

Comment: @SJ28 the opto output doesn't care - providing the Vcc pin is 12 volts higher than the GND connection, both can be floated up or down by a thousand volts. It's all relative.

Comment: ok, understood. How would you go about implementing this circuit but without isolation? Saying that the requirements are as previously specified but without isolation. Thanks

Comment: @SJ28 using an opto-isolator without input to output isolated voltages is not illegal. So, use the same circuit and pretend that there's no isolation inside the chip!!